# How can I print the lines in STDIN in random order in Perl?

Tags: perl, unix, sorting, random

I want to do the inverse of [sort(1)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/sort/) : randomize every line of **stdin** to **stdout** in Perl.

Comment: GNU coreutils' shuf [http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html] does exactly this, but in C.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I bet real Perl hackers will tear this apart, but here it goes nonetheless.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'shuffle';

my @lines = ();
my $bufsize = 512;
while(<STDIN>) {
    push @lines, $_;
    if (@lines == $bufsize) {
        print shuffle(@lines);
        undef @lines;
    }
}
print shuffle(@lines);
```

Difference between this and the other solution:

- Will not consume all the input and then randomize it (memory hog), but will randomize every $bufsize lines (not truly random and slow as a dog compared to the other option).
- Uses a module which returns a new list instead of a in place editing Fisher - Yates implementation. They are interchangeable (except that you would have to separate the print from the shuffle). For more information type perldoc -q rand on your shell.

Comment: Why do you use $current? Why would you manually maintain the length of the array when the array already knows this?

Comment: Because I make mistakes :-) Fixed.

Comment: I think you want if (@lines == $bufsize).  As is, you will shuffle every 514 lines.

Comment: I'm curious - Why do you think "real Perl hackers" would tear it apart? It's readable, it uses strict and warnings, and it gets the job done.

Comment: Okay, my mistake. I thought you meant those who would turn it into one line of unreadable gibberish. *Real* Perl hackers understand the difference between production code and "Perl golf," and aside from fixing a few typos, wouldn't have a problem with your code. :-)

Comment: @dehmann: I say so myself in the answer, which the OP accepted... I even state the reason for this non truly randomness.

Answer (score 6):

This perl snippet does the trick :

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
# randomize cat

# fisher_yates_shuffle code copied from Perl Cookbook 
# (By Tom Christiansen & Nathan Torkington; ISBN 1-56592-243-3)

use strict;

my @lines = <>;
fisher_yates_shuffle( \@lines );    # permutes @array in place
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    print $line;
}

# fisher_yates_shuffle( \@array ) : generate a random permutation
# of @array in place
sub fisher_yates_shuffle {
    my $array = shift;
    my $i;
    for ($i = @$array; --$i; ) {
        my $j = int rand ($i+1);
        next if $i == $j;
        @$array[$i,$j] = @$array[$j,$i];
    }
}

__END__
```

Answer (score 5):

```
use List::Util 'shuffle';
print shuffle <>
```

Or if you worry about last lines lacking \n,

```
chomp(my @lines = <>);
print "$_\n" for shuffle @lines;
```

Comment: This is the equivalent of TheSnide's solution using shuffle (eats everything up first, then shuffles)